# Merge acronym and glossary lists and display acronyms both short and long

Tags: glossaries

My current glossary looks like this:

[image]

What I'd like to do is:

1. Have the acronym-list print the short **and** the long version of the acronym, like this:

> **FPS** (Frames Per Second)  Text describing the acronym

2. "Merge" the glossary and the acronym list into one single list. This should also order the acronyms and the glossary-entries together, so that the acronym "FPS" would be between the glossary-entries "App" and "Heap".

I've checked out the huge user-manual for glossaries and some of the questions here, but no luck. Also, I found this [How to combine Acronym and Glossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8946/how-to-combine-acronym-and-glossary), which I can accept as a last resort, but I'd like to put them both in one list.

---

The merged glossary would be something like this:

> **activity**  Eine Art Controller[...] 6,19
>
> **FPS** (Frames Per Second)  Gibt an, wie oft der[...] 4,18,19,26
>
> **Heap**  Ein Baum, welcher die Heap[...] 5,10,81

Where `activity` and `Heap` are normal glossary entries and `FPS` is an acronym.

---

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[toc, nopostdot]{glossaries}
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{glossar.tex}
\newcommand{\Gloss}[1]{\textit{\Gls{#1}}}
\newcommand{\gloss}[1]{\textit{\gls{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Glosspl}[1]{\textit{\Glspl{#1}}}
\newcommand{\glosspl}[1]{\textit{\glspl{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Some text goes here \Gloss{glossar:acro:jvm} yada yada yada...

\cleardoublepage
\printglossary[title=Glossar]

\end{document}
```

That creates this output:

> Some text goes here *Java Virtual Machine (JVM)* yada yada yada...

and the second time

> Some other text later in the document has a *JVM* related topic

Comment: Could you demo what your merged option would look like?

Comment: @EngBIRD I added a demo.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) we can work with. If you're using the `glossaries` package, then just remove the `acronym` package option to have a single glossary. For a short and long version with a description try `\setacronymstyle{long-short-desc}`.

Comment: Removing the `acronym` option from the package works for question 2, thanks for that! Though the `\setacronymstyle` is for displaying long and short *in the text*, right? I only want the long and short version *in the glossary*.

Comment: `\setacronymstyle` also sets how the `name` key (used in the glossary) is constructed, but it may be more appropriate to define a custom glossary style. What do you want _in the text_? Long only or short only? It really would help if you could provide [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) we can work with.

Comment: I added an MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was this:

To solve **Nr. 1**, I used [this older answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192391/82073) from **@Nicola Talbot**:

```
\setacronymstyle{long-short-desc}  % Print both long and short
\renewcommand*{\acronymentry}[1]{%
 \acronymfont{\glsentryshort{#1}} (\textnormal{\glsentrylong{#1}})} % Print it the way I want
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{glossar.tex} % Or define them directly...
```

To solve **Nr. 2**, Nicola helped me in the comments directly, by pointing out that leaving the `acronym` package option out of the `\usepackage`-command would result in just what I wanted.

Together, the output now looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Could you please post how you formatted the \newglossaryentry in your file?

Comment: @Marcel not really sure what you're asking for. If you mean the style with which the glossary-items appear in the text, see my questions MWE.

Comment: I found it in Nicolas Thread. They glossary entries have to be formatted like this :\newacronym[description={set of tags for use in developing hypertext documents}]{html}{html}{Hyper Text Markup Language}